# Unable to Maximize Zoom Application using pyautogui

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

I have been working on a small project to automatically join a zoom meeting based on the timings mentioned in CSV file.
I am using the pyautogui library and navigating the mouse to specific coordinates.
The issue that I am facing is that everytime the zoom app opens, i manually have to maximize it.
I have used the following code to maximize the Zoom App window but it doesn't seem to work.

```
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
time.sleep(8)
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'up')
```

This seem to work pretty fine on other applications except Zoom, can you suggest any alternative way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the position of the icon used to maximize the window and use:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(position)
pyautogui.click()
```

or you could get a screenshot of desktop with zoom opened, cut it (with gimp or anything like that) to show only the "maximize" icon and use

```
position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("ImageOfIcon.png")
pyautogui.moveTo(position)
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: I changed the whole code and used the .locateOnScreen() everywhere. Works for any window size now. Thanks!